# Select a modification in hg diff

Tags: mercurial, diff

with

```
hg diff
```

mercurial show me the modifications, separated by `@@`.
I can get only one of them?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows, I would recommend installing TortoiseHg and using

```
hgtk status
```

Comment: TortoiseHg runs on Linux (and possibly macs) too.

Answer (score 2):

The modifications separated by `@@` are named *"patch hunk"* or simply *"hunk"*. You can use the [`record` extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RecordExtension) (disabled by default).

Comment: but this extension is only interactive

Comment: Indeed. Perhaps you could add details to you question, it quite --- short.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output of `hg diff` into a program like [`filterdiff`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/filterdiff) to further refine the patch.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, try the [hgview](http://www.logilab.org/project/hgview) program. It has a pretty nice interface.